# Scale and centre align <img> in hidden overflow div tag

Tags: css, image, alignment, scale

I'm creating a new website for myself, and as a photographer/videographer, image content is the first thing I want people to see on my page.

Here is my code so far.

HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow_background">
            <img src="IMAGEADDRESS.JPG" class="slideshow" align="middle"/>
            </div>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow_background {
    width: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: centre;
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -50%;
    max-height: 700px;
}


img.slideshow {
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 700px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve with this, is what is done here: http://www.atcofficial.com.

As you can see, the image stays centred whatever the window width is. It also scales up/down depending on how zoomed in or out you are. This site is made with Squarespace,  so I'm imagining it's some form of fancy javascript/jquery or something along those lines.

With CSS, I am able to get the image to either stay centred, **OR** to scale up and down, but not both at the same time. That's what I'm trying to achieve here. Is there away to combine the two so that this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try using CSS `background-size:cover;`. Cover shrinks and expands to fit various window sizes, without distorting the image. If the screen size ratio is different than the image, than it will crop the edges depending on how you have it positioned (top, bottom, center, right, left, center). Keeping the image in proportion is the key feature of background-size:cover;. Because its a background and not an image, you can easily place elements on top of it.

Here is a [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/TalkingRock/p834kjpd/) you can play with. Expand and contract the window to see the background image adjust in size. The only code your are interested in is listed below. (The rest of the CSS in the example is for styling only, and to make the div display at 100% width and height).

```
background-image:url(http://i.imgur.com/OaE8VAj.jpg);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:center center;
background-size:cover;
-webkit-background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
-o-background-size:cover;
```

---

### Follow Up

Yes, there are CSS3 slideshow galleries. Here is one that looks attractive, and is responsive: https://github.com/css-slider/image-slider. Here is a tutorial on creating a CSS3 slideshow from Smashing Magazine: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/25/pure-css3-cycling-slideshow/.

You probably already know the information below, but what you have to check into before investing much time in the technology (CSS3 or JavaScript), is how the gallery will display on older browsers and handheld devices, and is there an easy work-around for these devices.

One technique would be to place the gallery in a separate div that can be hidden for older browsers/devices. Then use the background-size:cover, or another technique, as a fallback. Also remember that IE10 and IE11 on a touch screen can be glitchy, and need testing as well. Without going to far beyond the scope of your original question, there are several good ways to detect devices/browsers including Modernizr, Matt Stow's Layout Engine, Categorizr.js and Internet Exlporer's Conditional Comments.

Side Note: The example website listed in the question displayed a large single image as background, and if there was a slideshow, it was not working on this end using the latest version of Firefox.

Comment: Would it then be possible to make the background image into a slideshow of 'x' number of images using CSS transitions or something similar?

Comment: Yes, there are CSS3 slideshows, and the resources are listed at the bottom of the answer.